# What happens if SQL connection pool opening and closing continuously in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sqlconnection

What happens if SQL connection pool opening and closing continuously in SQL Server? If anyone knows, please tell me.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLDbConn"].ConnectionString);
SqlConnection.ClearPool(con);
```

Comment: When you open a connection, one connection is taken from the pool and passed back to you. If you close the connection, that connection is returned to the pool ..... or what else are you asking about??

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. i had doubt that whether app pool create for each user accessing a site or single for app pool all user

Answer (score 1):

You should check out the freely available MSDN documentation on the topic, which you could easily find with any of your favorite search engines....

E.g.

- [SQL Server Connection Pooling (ADO.NET)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Here, the documentation says:

> Only connections with the same configuration can be pooled. ADO.NET **keeps several pools** at the same time, one for each configuration. Connections are separated into pools by connection string, and by Windows identity when integrated security is used. Connections are also pooled based on whether they are enlisted in a transaction.

So why the connection pool is system-wide per server, there are several pools active at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to use the `using` statement

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("..."))
{

}
```

By this you dont have to worry about closing the connection once the query is executed and the resources are managed automatically.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer. My issue is App Pool Count is keep on increasing it takes time to release. large number of user use my site.